# Stash embed not working in EE3 after update

Tags: stash, ee3

***Have edited this question in light of further information subsequent to the initial question being posted...***

Have Stash 3.0.4 running on EE 3.4.6.

Have migrated an EE2 site that is working fine, to EE3.

Several of the templates are simply a one-line {stash:embed} tag which redirects to one of several shared templates.  The redirect templates look like this:

```
{stash:embed:_resources-cat-index process="start"}
```

This redirection approach works fine in EE2, but in EE3 the embeds are failing: rather than running the template defined in the embed, an error is displayed of this form:

> **The following errors were encountered**
>
> `Stash: the file "/var/sites/e/ee3.2gc.org/system/expressionengine/templates/default_site/stash_templates.group/_wwd-index.html" was not found.`

Because the error occurs before a template is loaded, there is no debugging information showing beyond this error message.

I have tried removing all the one other extension that uses the `template_fetch_template` method but it makes no difference.

Any ideas what might be a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have defined a list of allowed extensions for embeds in your config, and that your embed is using one of them, e.g.:

```
$config['stash_file_extensions'] = array('html', 'md', 'css', 'js', 'rss', 'xml');
```

Make sure that you have defined the path to your stash templates:

```
$config['stash_file_basepath'] = "/path/to/my/stash/templates/"
```

If you have checked these and it still isn't working, there are a few possibilities:

- Verify that the `stash_fetch_template` and `template_fetch_template` extensions are installed. If not, delete and reinstall Stash.
- Check which other add-ons use the `template_fetch_template` extension hook. You may find that disabling them causes your embed to work, in which case you should contact the author of the add-on responsible and ask them to check the value of the `ee()->extensions->last_call` property when the hook is triggered, and to return a value from their extension.
- You may have other tags throwing errors which would interrupt the template parser and stop it completing. You can either use the template debugger to see which tag is processed last and/or remove other tags from the template until the embed works, to figure out which tag(s) are the culprit.

Comment: As per initial post the embeds are working fine when used within EE2.  The file extension list is defined and basepath set (implied by embeds working in EE2, but just for clarification).  Not sure where in EE3 I'd check on the 'fetch' templates being installed - could you clarify this please?  Thx.

Comment: Look at the `exp_extensions` table in your database and see which add-ons have `template_fetch_template` listed in the `method` column. To temporarily disable the add-on extension, set the value in the `enabled` column to `n`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: very annoying in the end.  Lack of a trailing slash in the `$config['stash_file_basepath']` setting... grr!